# i'm getting this error whenever i run my app caused by java.lang.nullpointerException:findViewbyId(R.id.btn_start)must not be null

Tags: java, android, xml, kotlin, android-layout

Layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"    
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/image"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_app_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="QuizApp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
         />

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
        app:cardElevation="5dp"
        >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="16dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="Welcome"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:text="please enter your name"
                android:textColor="#7A8089"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"/>

            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox"
                >

                <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatEditText
                    android:id="@+id/et_name"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:hint="Name"
                    android:textColor="#363A43"
                    android:textColorHint="#7A8089"/>

            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btn_start"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:background="@color/black"
                android:text="start"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:textColor="@color/purple_200">

            </Button>

        </LinearLayout>

    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'kotlin-android'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 31
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.quizapp"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 31
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
        buildFeatures{
            viewBinding true
        }
    }
    buildToolsVersion '31.0.0'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.6.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.4.0'
}
```

MainActivity

```
package com.example.quizapp
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var button: Button
    private lateinit var textView: AutoCompleteTextView

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_quiz_question)

        button = findViewById(R.id.btn_start)
        textView = findViewById(R.id.et_name)

        if (textView.toString().isEmpty()){
            Toast.makeText(this,"please enter your name", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please format your code properly.  You don't need 3 or 4 blank lines between every line.

Comment: Is the layout you posted `activity_quiz_question.xml`?

Comment: @laalto yes it is

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 1):

Probably setContentView(R.layout.activity_quiz_question) is incorrect !
Your layout is activity_main, replace setContentView(R.layout.activity_main) instead of setContentView(R.layout.activity_quiz_question) and make sure your ui code is in the activity_main.xml file

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

private lateinit var button: Button
private lateinit var textView: AutoCompleteTextView

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    button = findViewById(R.id.btn_start)
    textView = findViewById(R.id.et_name)

    if (textView.toString().isEmpty()){
        Toast.makeText(this,"please enter your name", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
}
```